# Testing a class that extends from generic abstract class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit5

Well, this is the first time that I'm doing  testing. The code I have is the next:

```
public abstract class Value<T>
{
    private T value;

    public Value(T aValue) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T value() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Value<?> that = (Value<?>) o;
        return Objects.equals(value, that.value);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(value);
    }
}
```

Then I create a class extending from the above class:

```
public class DateOfBirth extends Value<LocalDate>
{
    private DateOfBirth(LocalDate aDate) {
        super(aDate);
    }

    public static DateOfBirth of(LocalDate aDate) {
        return new DateOfBirth(aDate);
    }
}
```

Finally I run the next text, but it didn't pass.

```
public class DateOfBirthUnitTest
{
    @Test
    public void birthDateShouldBeInstanceFromLocalDate() {
        DateOfBirth theActual = DateOfBirth.of(LocalDate.of(1997, 12, 10));

        assertNotNull(theActual.value()); //This test is failing
    }
}
```

Why "theActual.value()" calling is returning a NULL value? How can I solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest use good IDE like eclipse, IntelliJ and use tools like SonarLint, it will find such errors for you as soon as you save code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typing mistake...??

change

```
 public Value(T aValue) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

To

```
 public Value(T value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

and it should work!